# React-Native navigation doesn't recognize params

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have a typescript react-native application. I have used navigation with some sucess but in this case, no matter what I do, the id, filename, and file are all undefined.

Here is the code with the issue. I know according to react-native navigation doing what I'm doing with the file isn't necessary great coding practice, but this is just displaying a file, so it's not a huge deal. (I am storing the filename and id in a sqlite database). I added the useState hoping that the file gets passed or change that it can change the state.

```
    export type Props = {
      navigation: PropTypes.func.isRequired;
      id:PropTypes.int.isRequired;
      filename:Protypes.string.isRequired;
      file:{ 
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired;
        uri: PropTypes.path.isRequired;
        type: PropTypes.mime.isRequired};
    };
    
    const FileViewScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({navigation,id,filename,file}) => {
      console.log("File View Screen?")
      console.log("currentFile");
      console.log(id)
      console.log(currentFile)
      console.log(filename)
      console.log(file)
      const [currentFile,setCurrentFile] = useState(file);
```

Here is where the user gets routed to the FileScreen. Here I was testing to see if any id is passed, I'm aware that the id needs changed to the id and not 1 but this was testing.

```
const HomeScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({navigation}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [file, setFile] = useState({});
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const downloadFile = async () => {
    try {
      ...

      const newEntry = {
        name: 'ImageFileName' + Math.random().toString(),
        uri: result.path,
        type: result.mime,
      };
      const res = await addFile(result.path);
      console.log(res)
      navigation.navigate('FileView', { id:1,filename:res,file:newEntry });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('downloadFile error', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles}>
      <Text>Welcome Home</Text>
      {loading && <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} color="#000" />}
      {!loading && (
        <>
          <Button
            title="Start Recording"
            onPress={downloadFile}
          />
```

Here is the addFile function. I don't think this matters but I've been wrong before. Here

```
export const addFile = file_path => {
  db.transaction(txn => {
    console.log("db transaction")
    console.log(file_path)
    const response = txn.executeSql(
      'INSERT INTO files(file_path,uploaded) VALUES (' +
        file_path +
        ',' +
        false +
        ')',
      (sqlTxn, res) => {
        console.log("adding")
        console.log(`${file_path} video added successfully`);
        return file_path;
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error on adding file ' + error.message);
        return 0;
      },
    );
  });
  console.log(resopnse)
};
```

In my app.js (i do have a working register and, login, home screen. Right now this is the only time I have an issue.

```
  <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initalRoute}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login">
          {props => (
            <LoginScreen {...props} setToken={setUserToken} setUser={setUser} />
          )}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {props => (
              <HomeScreen {...props}/>
            )}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="FileView">
          {props =>(
             <FileViewScreen {...props} />
             )}
        </Stack.Screen>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Things that I've tried.

1. I tried to change the RecordingView in app.js to make sure it's specifically passing props
2. I've changed props to be only an id, only a filename, or only the newentry.
3. I've tried to set the state as the file in case it gets passed later.

Things that I haven't tried

1. I haven't put this in a button. That's the main thing I haven't been able to find if navigation.navigate only works on a push event. I don't see any documentation stating that.

Comment: When you navigate to a screen the params passed are available under [route](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params) prop. Have you tried printing out your entire prop object to see if the params are missing from route ?

Comment: @sushrut619 can you post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Not sure why I have to do that in this route and in other routes I don't though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `FileViewScreen` is a child component of some parent view then `id,filename,file` will be available from component `props` object. If instead you navigate to `FileViewScreen` from another screen then `id,filename,file` will be part of `route` prop.

To account for both use cases you could so something like this

```
const FileViewScreen: React.FC<Props> = (props) {
  // try extracting props from root prop object
  let { id,filename,file } = props;


  // if navigation route params are available, 
  // then extract props from route.params instead
  // you could also check if id, filename, file etc are null
  // before extracting from route.params
  const { route }  = props;
  if (route && route.params) {
    ({ id,filename,file } = route.params);
  }
  ...
}
```